# Installing Ubuntu inside Windows 8

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, windows-8

I have been using Windows and ubuntu alongside each other for quite some time. Till Windows 7, things were fine. I installed Ubuntu inside Windows and all was fine. At startup, I would be asked if I want to boot Windows 7 or Ubuntu and I could choose.

However, starting from Windows 8, I could still install Ubuntu inside Windows 8 but while starting up, Windows 8 boots up automatically and in the end I am asked if I wanted to boot Ubuntu. Then if I choose Ubuntu, the machine restarts again and Ubuntu is booted. This is very annoying. If I want to use Ubuntu, I have to boot the device twice.

I have tried reinstalling many times, with different version of Ubunutu, it is always the same. Is there any work around this to make it like Windows 7? Or do you suggest some other method of installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 8?

Comment: What do you mean "Windows 8 boots up automatically and in the end I am asked to boot Ubuntu"?

Comment: @Alaa It means exactly what it says, it sounds weird I know. If at that stage I choose Windows 8 instead of Ubunutu, I am directly taken to my Windows 8 desktop without any further delay. So Windows has already loaded by that time.

Comment: That method is unsupported with Windows 8 and all Ubuntu releases. Things might change in the future, or they might not, you'll have to wait and see.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Ubuntu INSIDE Windows (via the Wubi installer) is not supported for Windows8.
See the warnings on the official WUbi page: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer